# How to Dynamically Append Custom D3/SVG Element in Angular

Tags: angularjs, svg, d3.js, directive

I'm trying to add dynamically a custom element whenever users click on button, which will render an SVG cube via D3.js code.

I've added an ng-click directive to a button element that invokes a function to dynamically append a custom cube element, and then I invoke $rootScope.$apply() in order to 'apply' the custom directive, but that does not work.

Here's the complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>AngularJS, directives, and D3.js</title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.js">
  </script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
 </head>

 <body ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="MyController as svgc">
  <button ng-click="svgc.addCube()">Add a Cube</button><br/>
  <cube></cube>

  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller("MyController", function($rootScope) {
       var svgc = this;

       svgc.addCube = function() {
        //var cube = angular.element('cube');
          var cube = document.createElement('cube');
          document.body.appendChild(cube);
          $rootScope.$apply();
       }   
    }); 

    myapp.directive('cube', function() {
      function link(scope, el, attr) {
        // d3.select(el[0]).append('svg');
        el = el[0];

        // CUSTOM CODE FOR RENDERING A CUBE 
        var width = 300, height = 300;
        var points1 = "50,50 200,50 240,30 90,30";
        var points2 = "200,50 200,200 240,180 240,30";
        var fillColors = ["red", "yellow", "blue"];

        var svg = d3.select(el)
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width",  width)
                    .attr("height", height);

        // top face (parallelogram)
        var polygon = svg.append("polygon")
                         .attr("points", points1)
                         .attr("fill",   fillColors[1])
                         .attr("stroke", "blue")
                         .attr("stroke-width", 1);

         // front face (rectangle)
         svg.append("rect")
            .attr("x", 50)
            .attr("y", 50)
            .attr("width",  150)
            .attr("height", 150)
            .attr("fill", fillColors[0]);

         // right face (parallelogram)
         var polygon = svg.append("polygon")
                          .attr("points", points2)
                          .attr("fill",   fillColors[2])
                          .attr("stroke", "blue")
                          .attr("stroke-width", 1);
      }

      return {
         link: link,
         restrict: 'E'
      }
    });
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I've seen examples on stackoverflow that use templates for adding custom elements, but this scenario requires the dynamic generation of SVG elements via D3, so I don't see how a template-based solution would work.

I'm sure the solution is simple...suggestions are welcome:)

Answer (score 0):

I fiddled with the code and came up with this solution:

```
  <script>
    var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
    myapp.controller("MyController", function($compile, $scope) {
       var svgc = this;

       svgc.addCube = function() {
          var cube = document.createElement('cube'); 
          cube.className = "cube"; 
          document.body.appendChild(cube);
          $compile(angular.element('.cube'))($scope);
       }   
    }); 
...
</script>
```